# Write a code in R, Using formula for required replicates

Tags: r, expression

write a function `required.replicates` that requires two parameters, `delta` and `sigma` and has two optional parameters, `z.alpha = 1.959964` and `z.beta=0.8416212`.Write this function to return a list with 3 elements.  The first element will be a list containing the four parameters used to calculate `r.exact` and `r.integer`. You may choose your own name, but this element should be accessible by something like `result[[1]]` - see the unit tests. The other two elements will be values `r.exact` and `r.integer` corresponding to the decimal and next largest integer values. sigma=c(4,8) delta=c(5,10).

My code:

```
z.alpha = 1.959964
z.beta = 0.8416212
sigma=c(4,8)
delta=c(5,10)

required.replicates <- function( z.alpha =1.959964,z.beta =0.8416212, sigma, 
delta)
{

 result <- list(z.alpha, z.beta, sigma, delta)
 print(r.exact<-(2*(z.alpha+z.beta)^2*(sigma)^2/(delta)^2))
 print(r.integer<- ceiling(r.exact))
 return( x <-list(result, r.exact,r.integer) )
```

}

## unit Test Given to test it

```
  if(length(find("required.replicates"))>0) {
  print(total.points <- total.points + 2)
  r.4.5.result <- required.replicates(delta=5,sigma=4)
  r.4.5.pars <- r.4.5.result[[1]]
  if(length(r.4.5.pars)==4) {
   print(total.points <- total.points + 2)
   if(r.4.5.pars$delta==5) {
    print(total.points <- total.points + 1)
    } else {
     print("Not returning delta parameter")
      }
     if(r.4.5.pars$z.alpha==1.959964) {
    print(total.points <- total.points + 1)
    } else {
     print("Not returning z.alpha parameter")
     }
     } else {
     print("Not returning all parameters")
      }
      if(r.4.5.result$r.integer==11) {
     print(total.points <- total.points + 2)
     } else {
     print("Incorrect reps for sigma=4 and delta=5")
      } 
     } else {
    print("required.replicates not defined")
   }
```

Its giving me error: Error in if (r.4.5.pars$delta == 5) { : argument is of length zero

Please Help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Try naming the elements of your `result` list to ensure the testing code can find the parameters I guess?

Comment: I have solved that error by naming list (result), but now I have new error Error in if (r.4.5.result$r.integer == 11) { : argument is of length zero   new code            required.replicates <- function( z.alpha =1.959964,z.beta =0.8416212, sigma, delta)
{
  f1<-z.alpha 
  f2<-z.beta
  f3<-sigma
  f4<-delta
  list1<-list(z.alpha=f1, z.beta=f2, sigma=f3, delta=f4) 
  list1 
  result <- list1
  print(r.exact<-(2*(z.alpha+z.beta)^2*(sigma)^2/(delta)^2))
  print(r.integer<- ceiling(r.exact))
  return( x <-list(result, r.exact,r.integer) )
}

Comment: I have name both lists(result and x) it solved error. Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

I have named both lists (x and result) and it problem solved. Thanks Marius

Comment: This is basically an admission that you made a typo. These are not really considered either good questions of good answers. The error I got was: "Error in print(total.points <- total.points + 2) : 
  object 'total.points' not found". Please read the basic information about what is a high qualtiy question on SO.

Comment: I didn't made a typo . I didn't know that I have to name both lists, so that my unit test can work. I am very new at R language(3rd week), I am sorry if you feel its stupid question but for me it was a learning opportunity.

Comment: you didn't find total points because I forgot to initiate total points=0 at the beginning of my code. I